# How to develop an application UI like Metro for Windows Vista/7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-metro

How to develop an application UI like Metro for Windows Vista/7

github recently released their official client for windows and is very similar to Metro

http://windows.github.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it in WPF by retemplating all the controls you use. There seem to be libraries that already do it to make apps look like the Zune Software or the GitHub client.

http://elysium.codeplex.com/

http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Telerik Rad Controls to create WinForms application in metro style theme.

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx

[Metro UI with Telerik Windows Forms Controls](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kt56u9XXt2E&noredirect=1)