# What framework was used to build the new Windows Github application?

Tags: github-for-windows

Github recently released a new [Windows application](http://windows.github.com/), with some very interesting UI ideas. Does anyone know what UI framework was used to build this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10725383/1454769)? Looks like that UI used by GhfW is called Metro-ui. This keyword can be useful.